# Creating date intervals for records from same timestamp column

Tags: sql

I have a table 'dates' where 2 columns represent the date from which an object's description is valid, and the date up until it is valid, (valid_from & valid_to), such as the following:

```
 ID   valid_from      valid_to      removed

  1   2019-06-27         -           false
  1        -         2019-06-26      true  
  1   2019-05-16         -           false   
  1   2019-05-08         -           false
  1   2019-05-07         -           false
```

What I need to do is get clear time intervals for all these rows, defining a valid_from and valid_to for each one.

Valid_to dates correspond to a removal of the record with the closest valid_from date prior to itself, so these 2 rows should therefore be collapsed into one, keeping the removed=true value (although that is not a priority). In this case, for example, rows 2 and 3 should be collapsed.

Then, for each row where valid_to is NULL (removed=false), the closest valid_from date greater than that row's valid_from should be inserted. 
The most recent row (which is the first one) wont have a record after it, so the valid_to date will remain NULL.

Therefore, the yielded result would be:

```
 ID   valid_from      valid_to      removed

  1   2019-06-27         -           false
  1   2019-05-16     2019-06-26      true  
  1   2019-05-08     2019-05-16      false
  1   2019-05-07     2019-05-08      false
```

This can't be done by hard-coding the values or condition limits, since this is just a piece of a much bigger table, and the operation should be performed for each ID group.

---

I have tried to use the TOP statement on a subquery inside a INSERT INTO statement, but couldn't figure out how to sequence the processes needed to achieve this result.

Help would be much appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I specifically didn't include one because I'm using none of them, I'm working with a specific adaptation of SQL for a company database. I have yet to find a missing feature though, so I think almost any answer will suit me.

Comment: `TOP` isn't standard SQL to begin with...

Comment: Correct...it does mix in some functionalities. Maybe I can't specify the query as much as ideally...should I remove @a_horse_with_no_name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just want `lead()`:

```
select valid_from, next_valid_to,
       coalesce(next_result, result) as result
from (select t.*,
             lead(coalesce(valid_from, valid_to)) over (partition by id order by coalesce(valid_from, valid_to)) as next_valid_to,
             lead(removed) over (partition by id order by coalesce(valid_from, valid_to)) as next_result
      from t
     ) t
where valid_from is not null;
```